# Return address modification causes calling convention exception

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, return, calling-convention

I am experimenting with the modification of the return address of a function. I sucessfully made that function to skip an instruction and no error happened, i.e. the program executed without any errors.

However I created another function and tried to manually control the program flow to follow: main->f->g->main. This happens as expected, but after the program reaches the end of the main function an assert happens which is saying:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention. occurred

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

void g();
void f();

void* default_return_address = 0;
void* new_return_address = &g;


void g() {
    std::cout << "g ran\n";

    __asm {
        push edx  // push edx to stack because we don't want to modify it
        mov edx, default_return_address  // load default_return_address to edx
        mov [ebp + 0x04], edx  // replace current function's return address with edx
        pop edx  // restore edx
    };
}

void f() {
    __asm {
        push eax  // push eax to stack because we don't want to modify it
        push edx  // push edx to stack because we don't want to modify it

        lea eax, default_return_address  // load address of default_return_address variable to eax
        mov edx, [ebp + 0x04]  // load the return address of the current function to edx
        mov [eax], edx  // store the current function's return address in eax

        mov edx, new_return_address  // load new_return_address to edx
        mov [ebp + 0x04], edx  // replace current function's return address with edx

        pop edx  // restore edx
        pop eax  // restore eax
    };
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    f();
    std::cout << x;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

If I don't use the `new_return_address` variable but move the `default_return_address` variable into `EDX` in the `f` function the program will run "as normal" and I get no error so the problem must be somewhere in `g`.

I tried to remove the `cout` but the result was the same. I also tried not to push and pop the stack. The `ESP` register has the same value before the program enters the asm block in `g` and after it leaves it.

What is different in `g` that causes this error to happen? And how can I "call" a function by returning into it?

Comment: This may be the optimizer playing tricks. Have you tried disabling it? Or at least explicitly declare the functions are `__cdecl` otherwise anything can happen.

Comment: *And how can I "call" a function by returning into it?*  Generally you don't; think about what stack state a function expects when execution reaches it: ESP points at a return address.  So you'd have to push a fake return address *and* then `push OFFSET target` / `ret` to emulate a `jmp`.  Or just `push OFFSET target` / `ret` to emulate a `jmp` tailcall.

Comment: @PeterCordes You cant `push` it because `esp` is somewhere else. The ret address is (presumably) at `[ebp + 0x04]`, admitting this function was called using either a cdecl or stdcall calling convention, we know this because those calling conventions clean up doing `mov esp, ebp; pop ebp; ret`.

Comment: @Havenard: I'm talking about emulating `jmp` by pushing a *new* return address, not modifying the existing one; as I pointing it as the start of another function can't work.  (Or simulates making your parent doing a tailcall to it, depending on what's on the stack above your return address, i.e. stack memory you don't own).  Of course `push/ret` can't work either in MSVC inline asm unless it's inside a `_declspec(naked)` function; in a plain function you'd tailcall with ESP pointing somewhere else.

Comment: @Havenard The optimizer is disabled. I tried to explicitly declare functions as `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` non of them solved the problem.
I would like to have the stack unwound before `g` is called. I want to create a scheduler and the task switching is going to be initiated by external interrupt. And I want the interrupt handler not to return to the old address but to a different task.
TBH I didn't look up how a scheduler work because I want to take it as a challenge to make my own. (I don't want to use it in production code :)) Is there some other way to make the code behave this way?

Comment: `g` is already a pointer, maybe it's reading the address of `g()` from `&g` that is causing problems.

Comment: @Havenard I tried it but the same happens :(

Comment: Look at the generated code.

Comment: Yeah, it's debugging time... look at the generated assembly, see what the hell is going on, maybe place some breakpoints and inspect the stack manually.